# Android | How can I get X or Y coordinate value with getLocationInWindow()?

Tags: java, android

I want to get txtView Y coordinate value and set that value to a text view. How could I do that? I found several examples, I can print the value of the entire location, but can't do that for one value, for X or for Y, just for both with textNewView.setStringValueOf(test)); Please, there is someone who can offer me a solution? Thank you!

```
txtView = findViewById(R.id.txtView);
txtNewView = findViewById(R.id.txtNewView);

int test[] = new int[2];
txtView.getLocationInWindow(test);

int a = test[1];

txtNewView.setText(String.valueOf(a)); // Return 0
// txtNewView.setText(String.valueOf(test)); // Return l@a36079
```

Comment: `x=test[0]` and `y=test[1]`

Comment: @Darkman Ok, if I write ```int x = test[0];``` then ```txtNewView.setText(String.valueOf(x));```, the value will be 0

Comment: txtView is in the middle of the screen, I'm using ConstraintLayout, the values of X and Y can't be 0

Comment: That means you're getting the coordinates too early. Try it outside of `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`. Probably in `onWindowFocusChanged()` or somewhere else that being called after the layout has been measured. Careful: some methods are called multiple times.

Comment: @Darkman, thank you! I made a new function which is called after a click event in OnCreate(). It works. I want to reward your answer and if you want too, please answer (with that comment). Thank you again, be blessed!